# Thévenin theorem about Vth

Tags: thevenin

[image: enter code here]

This is a question related to the Thévenin theorem. I have found Rth by making 6 kΩ open but I'm having some difficulties finding Vth for this circuit. Can someone please guide me? Va is 6 V.

Comment: For computing \$I_O = \frac{V_a}{R_{total}}\$, \$R_{total} = \left( \left( 4 \: \textrm{k} \Omega+12 \: \textrm{k} \Omega \right) \vert \vert 16 \: \textrm{k} \Omega+4 \: \textrm{k} \Omega \right) \vert \vert 6 \: \textrm{k} \Omega+2\:\textrm{k} \Omega = 6 \: \textrm{k} \Omega\$. But there's no question about \$V_{TH}\$ and there isn't an output port specified for which to provide an answer. And specifying the port would likely cause \$R_{TH}\$ to be different from \$R_{total}\$, anyway.

Comment: It seems \$R_{Th}\$ is also also \$R_{total}\$ looking from the branch where \$I_o\$ is indicated in the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

General steps to get started solving many resistor problems, not this problem specifically.

1. Anywhere there are two resistors in direct series, combine them.
2. Redraw the circuit.
3. Anywhere there are two resistors in direct parallel, combine them.
4. Redraw the circuit.

Keep doing this until there are no more simple combinations.  Now you have a more clear image of the real problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have replaced your \$6k\Omega\$ resistor for calculating \$R_{TH}\$, I am assuming that you want to calculate the \$V_{TH}\$ across the same terminals.

Now what you have to calculate is the voltage across the open-circuit terminals. That can be calculated as \$V_a - V_{2k\Omega}\$. Where \$V_{2k\Omega}\$ is the voltage drop across \$2k\Omega\$ resistor, to calculate which you need to know the current through it. If you can replace the four resistors to the left of the voltage source with an equivalent resistance, then the current through the \$2k\Omega\$ resistor and hence \$V_{TH}\$ can be calculated easily.

Answer (score 0):

For calculating thevenin voltage, you have to calculate \$V_{oc}\$ which is open circuit voltage across the 6 Ω resistor. Open circuit the branch where current \$I_o\$ is flowing. Use mesh or nodal analysis to calculate \$V_{oc}\$.  Calculate \$R_{Th}\$ using a 1A current source to the right of 6Ω resistor.You have to short circuit voltage source. Connect negative terminal of the current source to ground. The voltage you get on top of 1A current source is Thevenin resistance.  With these steps you get Thevenin voltage and resistance. Replace the circuit to the left of the current \$I_o\$ flowing branch with Thevenin voltage source and Thevenin resistance in series with it.